Does anyone know the interpretation of these characters which are stamped onto my Chinese brush work painting? (Characters identified: 柳橋之印)
I'm guessing that the painting dates to around the 18th century and that this seal represents the artist name.
The medium is ink and brush on paper.


rightmost two characters look a lot like 柳橋 "willow bridge", so 柳橋?印

Thanks for your attempt.  Does anyone  have more input?
