I'm having a problem translating the signature on this painting. Can anyone help?
**I have two paintings that*were definitely done by the same artist but I presume were signed with different forms of the artist signature. One is signed "Bai Shi Shen Ren" (Qi Baishi) but the one on this image says something different. Both have identical artist seals. Is this another one of Baishi's names?

it is 柳橋熊楠 , never heard of this name, and can't find it on the net. only found the name 熊楠 who is a Japanese writer, doesn't seem to be the author of this signature

Wow! That's interesting! This is a Japanese name?

@TangHo that first character is 柳, this is the same seal as https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/58508

Yes. That was my post.

It would be a big help to know whether or not this is Japanese script or Chinese  script

I checked the stamp. It reads:
3之柳1
4印桥2（digits are the sequense）
this four characters, namely, 柳桥之印, means the stamp of 柳桥(an actual place)
As is mentioned by others 南方熊楠 is living between 1867.4.15 and 1941.12.29.
While 齐白石 is between 1864.1.1 to 1957.9.6.
The fact that 南方熊楠 is close to 孙中山 at that time, means that he does have access to some of the paintings of 齐白石.
However, do note that 齐白石 is not the only person identified as 白石山人. In fact the name “白石” was given to him originally by his teacher, according to an obscure famous artist 白石山人, so take heed.
See this old wiki page:https://zh.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%E9%BD%90%E7%99%BD%E7%9F%B3&direction=next&oldid=181943
(I don't know why they removed the part of the origin of his name, like it's not important, come on.)

Great job Ecne! I'd sure like to have access to information on Nanfeng Xiong Nan.

Maybe it possibly could have been a dedication painting

The context isn't so clear but I guess 柳橋 is a place name and 熊楠 refers to 南方熊楠. It means the painting is done at 柳橋 by 南方熊楠.

Thank you sigterm for your response. I will do more research
